# Custom images with UISlider doesn't show on the device

Tags: ios, custom-controls, uiimage, uislider

Everything works on the simulator without a problem. However when I put it on my device it only show the `ThumbImage`. It is just really strange. I'm thinking this could be a iOS version issue or memory issue. My device is iPhone 3GS iOS 4.1. Xcode Version 3.2.5.

```
@interface BlueChalkSlider : UISlider {}
@end

@implementation BlueChalkSlider
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder: decoder])) {      
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Chalk.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ChalklineBlue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ChalklineWhite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem Solved!!!

The simulator is NOT case sensitive. The Device is case sensitive. I've changed and make sure all my filenames are exactly the same with Case Sensitive.

e.g. `Chalkline` should be `ChalkLine`

Comment: This question & answer have saved my hours.Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you copying the resource files over (did you choose to make a copy of the images when you added them)? Try a Clean from the Build (or Run?) menu...and Build & Run again.

Comment: I deleted the app on my device and did a clean build, the problem persist.

Comment: I've had ghost issues like that without any definite solution. Short of making sure that both the simulator and your phone are running the same version (4.2/4.3?) and performing a clean build, it's boiled down to a combination of reboots (system and phone) and blind luck. Sorry I couldn't have been more helpful...